# Creating Dockerfile quickly

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wanted a docker image with adoptopenjdk in alpine; installed with:

- maven 3.6.3
- kubectl latest
- helm latest
- git
- maybe openshift

Is there a quick way to select a base image and then the aforementioned tools and get a Dockerfile, which I can further edit perhaps? It seems like something like that would be great to have and I expected it to be available. I went to Dockerhub and searching the tags, I can get maybe just the adoptopenjdk or maven or kubectl but not all-in-one bundle of my choosing. If there doesn't exist a thing like that what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: The Dockerfile system is pretty straightforward, especially if you can identify if the image you're starting from is Debian (or Ubuntu) or Alpine-based.  In many cases you'll actually want to install an application and not just a collection of unrelated tools; for these specific tools, given the need for credentials to access Kubernetes and other applications' Helm charts to install, I'd install the tools on the host directly.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, what do you mean by identify the image I'm starting with? What would be the reasons I choose one over the other (other than certain applications might not work in one or the other). What I'm trying to do at the moment is create a Dockerfile with these tools, start a Jenkins slave inside a K8 cluster, and run tests using these tools; therefore, I need it to be running inside a K8 pod. I will later most likely expand the tools that gets installed in this container.

Comment: Oh, you said up front that it's an Alpine image.  https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages lists everything in Alpine, and you can `RUN apk add ...` whatever you need (that's pre-packaged; Helm may not be).

Comment: Thanks David; that's definitely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer pulling some separately, there’s none much differences thou.